# Meaning of quasiperiodicity in classical KAM

Tags: analysis, definition, physics, dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics

I'm learning about the classical KAM theorem, and I can't quite infer precisely what the term "quasi-periodic solution" means in the theorem's statement.  I'm reading the following introductory note:

math.bu.edu/people/cew/preprints/introkam.pdf

and on the 15th page a discussion of nearly integrable systems starts and the classical KAM theorem is stated on 16 (this is all independent of pages 1-14).  Basically, the theorem is stated here as:

If $\omega^*$ is a set of frequencies badly approximable by rational numbers (in the sense of Definition 3.1), and if the integrable part of the Hamiltonian is nondegenerate at action variable $I^*$, then there is an $\epsilon_0$ s.t. as long as the non-integrable part of the Hamiltonian is analytic and bounded (in the sup norm sense) by $\epsilon_0$ then there exists a quasi-periodic solution with frequencies $\omega^*$.

Now, I'm under the impression from other sources that quasi-periodic on a Kronecker torus is basically no different from the frequencies being not rationally dependent, i.e. any set of frequencies that leads to non-periodic trajectories.  But when we no longer have the Kronecker tori in the perturbed case, I'm not really sure what the definition of a quasi-periodic trajectory/solution is.

Thanks a lot in advance for any insight!

Comment: The definition of quasi-periodic trajectory is the same, regardless of whether the system is integrable, perturbed, etc. The KAM states roughly that trajectories with "highly irrational" or diophantine frequencies survive small enough perturbations, almost surely. I am not sure what a Kronecker tori is (is it the same as Lagrangian tori ? i.e. the n-dimensional tori in 2n dimensional phase space ?

Comment: (with linear flow) If yes, then the whole point of KAM is that these tori DO survive, so your statement "we no longer have kronecker tori" is wrong.

Comment: thanks for your comment, what I mean by kronecker tori is just the subsets of phase space ${I} \times \mathbb{T}^n$ invariant under the flow of the integrable part of the hamiltonian.  I'm trying to see the detailed meaning behind the statement that "tori survive".  My shot-in-the-dark guess is that you can provide a map $\phi:\mathbb{T}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{T}^n$, ie from the torus to the phase space, where the image is invariant under the flow, and pulling back the vector field gives a constant flow with frequencies $\omega^*$

Comment: $\phi$ injective in my last comment

Comment: Well yes, essentially these diophantine tori get deformed after perturbation is added. It is very easy to understand this if you just simulate the so called 2D standard map. For $\epsilon=0$, these tori are basically horizontal lines in the action-angle plane. Once you increase $\epsilon$, the non-diophantine ones start disappearing, and diophantine ones are curves as shown here http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Chirikov_standard_map